# Line messaging API get bot profile issue

Tags: bots, line-api

As per the LINE [messaging API docs](https://devdocs.line.me/en/#getting-user-profiles),there is API for getting user profile information. When I using that API,

```
curl -X GET \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer cEet0ordwd4VsUHi9jnbQuWIY+fL5RKeSGP65HEbGtGznHQ4XOaOwaTDQqwLT0bI24oFKLtMvspYvPgi4qR3Bv1oMQp+Wak2x7TRSxsL/oqQN1kIzGTk9aK4ICxU6qK4tM0KHoAkjA1ahEJSswdB04t89/1O/w1cDnyilFU=' \
https://api.line.me/v2/profile
```

I'm getting the following response:

> {"message":null}. How can I get the bot profile information?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fulfill this conditions:
1. They have to use the latest LINE version.
2. They have to add the bot as their friend.

Comment: Profile information means the bot info. Yearly we can get the bot information using the bot token and the user info API.now it's getting a null value.

Comment: Oh, i taught it was the user's profile hahah.. it's better to reach out their helpdesk first, they'll give you a response within 24 hour.

Comment: Wait a minute, you did mention that it's `user` profile info, up there...? did i misstook it?